# Java Regex Tokenizing

Tags: java, regex, token, delimiter

new to regex here haha.

Let's say I have a string:

```
String toMatch = "TargetCompID=NFSC_AMD_Q\n" +
        
            "\n## Bin's verifix details";
```

Which shows up in a .cfg file as:

```
TargetCompID=NFSC_AMD_Q

## Bin's verifix details
```

I want to tokenize this into an array as:

```
{"TargetCompID", "NFSC_AMD_Q", "## Bin's verifix details"}
```

Current code but **doesn't out anything**:

```
static void regexTest(String regex, String toMatch) {
    Pattern patternTest = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcherTest = patternTest.matcher(toMatch);
    while (matcherTest.find()) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= matcherTest.groupCount(); i++) {
            System.out.println(matcherTest.group(i));
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String regex = "^[^=]+.*$" + "|" + "^#+.*$";
    String toMatch = "TargetCompID=NFSC_AMD_Q\n" +
            "\n" +
            "## Bin's verifix details";


    String testRegex = ".*";
    String testToMatch = "   ###  Bin";
    regexTest(regex1, toMatch);
    System.out.println("----------------------------");
```

//        regexTest(testRegex, testToMatch);

### EDIT

```
while (matcherTest.find()) {
    for (int i = 1; i < matcherTest.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println(matcherTest.group(i));
    }
```

prints:

```
TargetCompID
NFSC_AMD_Q
```

but not

```
## Bin's verifix details
```

why?

**also** this code:

```
while (matcherTest.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcherTest.group());
}
```

only prints

```
TargetCompID=NFSC_AMD_Q

## Bin's verifix details
```

Is **TargetCompID** and **NSFC_AMD_Q** not separated because we're not doing group(i)? and why is there a \newline printed?

Comment: Why are people downvoting? I'm confused. It's not like I didn't try to solve it myself after a couple hours of research. Please comment your reason for downvote.

Comment: I don't understand downvotes, you showed your attempts.

Comment: However don't edit your question by including my suggested solution and changing nature of your question. You can leave comment below my answer and I will address them. For ex: `for (int i = 1; i < matcherTest.groupCount(); i++)` should be: `for (int i = 1; i <= matcherTest.groupCount(); i++)`

Comment: Works now! Thank you :) I'll try to revert it back to the old one.

Comment: One last thing, for `while(matcherTest.find) {System.out.println(matcherTest.group()); }` why is there a new line/empty line printed?

Comment: Ok! I ran into another issue, if you could help that'd be amazing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45290104/regex-based-on-this-or-that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex in Java:

```
(?m)^([^=]+)=(.+)\R+^(#.*)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7PpUoz/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `(?m)`: Enable `MULTILINE` mode
- `^([^=]+)=`: Match till `=` and capture in group #1 followed by `=`
- `(.+)`: Match rest of line in group #2
- `\R+`: Match 1+ line breaks
- `^(#.*)`: match a full line starting with `#` in group #3