# Regex based on THIS or THAT

Tags: java, regex, token, delimiter

I am trying to parse the below:

```
"#SenderCompID=something\n" +
"TargetCompID=something1"
```

into an array of:

```
{"#SenderCompID=something", "TargetCompId", "something1"}
```

Using:

```
String regex = "(?m)" + "(" +     
    "(#.*) |" +                //single line of (?m)((#.*)|([^=]+=(.+))
    "([^=]+)=(.+) + ")";
String toMatch = "#SenderCompID=something\n" +
    "TargetCompID=something1";
```

which is outputting:

```
#SenderCompID=something
null
#SenderCompID
something
                       //why is there any empty line here?
TargetCompID=something1
null
                       //why is there an empty line here?
TargetCompID
something1
```

I understand what I'm doing wrong here. The 1st group is returning the entire line, the 2nd group is returning (#.*) if the line starts with # and null otherwise, the 3rd group is returning ([^=]+=(.+). The | is what I'm trying to do. I want to parse it based on **EITHER** the conditions for the **2nd group**

```
(#.*)
```

or for the **3rd group**

```
([^=]+)=(.+).
```

How?

**EDIT:** miswrote example code

Comment: You mentioned the pipe character in your question, but haven't explained the problem you're having with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex to get all 3 groups:

```
(?m)^(#.*)|^([^=]+)=(.*)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NGawzL/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `(?m)`: Enable `MULTILINE` mode
- `^(#.*)`: match a full line starting with `#` in group #1
- `|`: OR
- `^([^=]+)=`: Match till `=` and capture in group #2 followed by `=`
- `(.*)`: Match rest of line in group #3

Comment: your answer in the RegEx Demo is correct but not what you posted here. Thanks! Could you explain what the (?:) expression is doing here. I did something reading and what I gather is that whatever is captured afterwards is not stored but you wrapped the whole line with this so the whole line will not be captured?

Comment: did you get the recent comment?

Comment: `(?:..)` is called a non-capturing group.

Comment: Thank you for all your help.